# How to solve R(A,B,C,D,E) with FDs (A -> B, AB -> D, AC -> E)

Tags: rdbms, database, database-normalization

How do I ensure that `R(A,B,C,D,E`) is in `3NF` and `BCNF` with the following functional dependencies:

```
(A -> B, AB -> D, AC -> E)
```

If they are not in 3NF and BCNF, then how should I split?

I think that AC and ACB are keys. ABC are therefore prime attributes and DE are non-prime attributes.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: AC is the only *minimal* superkey (the only candidate key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relation is in BCNF if one of the following conditions hold:

> X → Y is a trivial functional dependency (Y ⊆ X)
>
> X is a superkey for schema R
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form)

In other words if the determinant, X, is a candidate key or Y is a subset of X then the relation is in BCNF. Furthermore if a relation is in BCNF it will also be in 3NF.

To determine if the determinant is a superkey you'd test it by its attribute closure of X. I'd recommend this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_P0EDfQZX9Y) if you're not familiar with it.